# Why Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Why Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

I understand that for $x \in [-1,1], \arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$. A proof of this fact uses Abel's theorem and an observation that $$\arctan(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\int_{0}^{x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-t^2)^ndt= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\int_{0}^{x} (t^{2n}) dt$$

But how do I see that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$ for some $a$.

**Edit**

I think I got it. We know that for $x \in [-1,1], \arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$, in other words on $[-1,1]$ $\arctan$ function is the power series. We know that a power series $f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n(x-a)^n$ which converges on $(a-R,a+R)$ with $R>0$ is infinitely differentiable on $(a-R,a+R)$ and $f^{(n)}(a)=c_n n!$. So $\arctan^{(2n+1)}(0)=(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1} (2n+1)!$ and $\arctan^{(2n)}(0)=0$. Now if we write down the Taylor series of $\arctan$ about $0$ we get exactly $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$.

Thanks to all who helped me to get it with their comments.

Comment: You managed to prove it in the first part and not believe the proof in the last part.

Comment: @KennyLau I do not see how $x \in [-1,1], \arctan(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ implies that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$, do you?

Comment: The series we have is for $a=0$. It tells us that $\arctan^{(2n+1)}(0)=(-1)^n(2n)!$ the even derivatives at $0$ being $0$

Comment: @Sergey Ugh, that pretty much seems like the definition of Taylor series to me.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for theorems like [this](http://www.math.wpi.edu/Course_Materials/MA1023C00/tayseries/node1.html) which states that the Taylor series at $x=0$ is unique.

Comment: This is only true if the distance of x to a is small enough.

Comment: that $\text{arctan}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\text{arctan}^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k$ for $|x-a|$ small enough is exactly the statement that $\text{arctan}(x)$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) around $a$, and the fact that $\text{arctan}'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ (where $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is clearly analytic) is enough for proving it is (on $\mathbb{R}$)  @KennyLau

Answer (score 1):

As so many people, you seem confused into believing one should use convergent series to understand a property of formal power series. Not so; formal power series are actually quite a bit easier to understand all by themselves. And a Taylor series is a formal power series: it just collects the information about repeated derivatives at a single point (here $0$), in a particular format. (It happens that $\arctan$ is an analytic function, so its values sufficiently close to the point$~0$ are given by evaluating its Taylor series, which converges there; this information is however quite independent from what you are asking about.)

You know that the derivative of $\arctan$ is $x\mapsto\frac1{1+x^2}$. As a rational function defined for $x=0$, the latter is indefinitely differentiable at $x=0$, and therefore so is $\arctan$; then both functions possess a Taylor series at $0$. The Taylor series of $x\mapsto\frac1{1+x^2}$, when multiplied by (the formal power series) $1+x^2$ must give the constant series $1$ (because the Taylor series of a product is the product of the Taylor series), and there is only one formal power series with that property, the series $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}(-x^2)^n=\sum_{i\geq0}(-1)^nx^{2n}$; this must be the Taylor series of $x\mapsto\frac1{1+x^2}$ at$~0$. It is also the term-by-term derivative of the Taylor series of $\arctan$, which then must be $\sum_{i\geq0}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$.

As you can see, almost no calculus is used, beyond the statement about the derivative of $\arctan$.

Comment: did you mean analytic instead of $C^\infty $ ? I don't get your "formal series" idea, do you know the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function $\phi(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x| < 1}$ whose Taylor series at $x = -1$ is the identically zero one ?

Comment: @user1952009 Certainly [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) is not an idea of _mine_; on the other hand my opinion that they should be taught _before_ considering numeric series does not seem widespread. And I meant analytic when I said so. Please note the difference between _having_ a Taylor series (which requires being $C^\infty$, and no more), and _begin equal_ to a function defined by a series with some positive radius of convergence (which is a characteristic property of analytic functions).

Comment: ... The map from functions $C^\infty$ at $0$ to formal power series in $x$ is surjective but not injective; in particular there are functions like your bump function that are nonzero but have a zero Taylor series. This implies that having a Taylor series, even if it happens to have positive radius of convergence, _does not imply being equal_ to the (analytic) function given by that series anywhere outside the point where the series is taken. The map from convergent series $S$ in $x$ to the corresponding analytic functions $f$ near $0$ is injective, as $S$ is the Taylor series of $f$.

Comment: what I mean is that your answer works much better if you use that $\text{arctan}'(x)$ is analytic (otherwise you can't know its Taylor series is the inverse of $1+x^2$)

Comment: @user1952009 Well $\arctan'=(x\to\frac1{1+x^2})$ is obviously analytic, but my argument does not use that, but only the easier fact that is _has_ a Taylor series. As $x\mapsto1+x^2$ clearly also has a Taylor series ($1+x^2$), and since the Taylor series of a product $fg$ of two functions both having Taylor series is the (formal series) product of the Taylor series of $f$ and $g$, it _must be_ that the Taylor series of $x\to\frac1{1+x^2}$ is the inverse of $1+x^2$ as a formal power series, as my answer indicates. Look Mom, no analysis (nor analytic functions)!

Answer (score 0):

If you have done some complex analysis arctan is sometimes defined as 
$$\arctan(z) =\frac{\log(z-i)-\log(z+i)}{2i}$$
Then you can use the Taylor expansion of log to prove it. Complex analysis also provides an interesting explanation for why the convergence is on $z \in [-1,1]$ : An analytic function has power series representation with convergence on any disc with radius smaller than distance to the pole closest to the center of the expansion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am not that fluent in complex analysis yet, as you can see from my edit above I am still trying to get basics of real analysis right.

Comment: ($z = \pm i$ is a branch point, not a pole. $ \ \ $ it is a pole of order $1$ of the derivative $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$)

Comment: Yes, but $\log(0)$ is a pole and $|\pm i| = |\pm 1| = 1$. So the individual log term expansions have radius 1.

Comment: @mathreadler $z=0$ is a singularity of $\log(z)$, but it is not a pole, it is a [branch point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point)